# Is it good practice to run different kernel variants for 'full' and 'partial-tail' blocks?

Tags: cuda, gpgpu, idioms

Often when you write a GPU kernel, assumptions regarding having full blocks/warps [1] are useful: You can shuffle between all threads in a warp; different warps can assume parts of the necessary work will be done by other warps etc. And when you have a significant amount of input to work on (many many block-fulls of threads), this translates into a meaningful performance gain.

Of course, if you make that assumption, then for the 'remainder' of your input data, or rather the single 'remainder' block of your grid which is less-than-full, you need to special-case. At best there's an extra `if (blockIdx.x < gridDim.x-1)` somewhere, at worst it's a whole other method of computing whatever it is you want.

One wonders whether perhaps it's a good idea to essentially have two separate kernels, one for the remainder block and one for the bulk of the data, so that the bulk kernel does not need to waste time on ensuring it's working on complete blocks?

Of course, in practice this could just be a static check, i.e.

```
template <bool IsRemainder>
__global__ void fooKernel(int* a, int* b)
{
    if (IsRemainder) {
        /* special-casing */
    }
    else {
        /* regular case, full block. */
    }
}
```

Notes:

- Assume all of the data is on the GPU and isn't going back to the CPU anytime soon.
- Assume the grid is one-dimensional.
- This allows the regular-case code to not make any checks at all about whether the block is full or not - the condition there is checked at run-time.

  [1] (in CUDA parlance; in OpenCL: workgroups and, umm, wavefronts, right?)

Comment: There are a lot of possible permutations and no general answer to a question this broad, I'm afraid  (for example, often doing the residual calculations on the host  in parallel with the GPU is a viable and performant option)

Comment: @talonmies: Trying to limit the scope of my question.

Answer (score 1):

Whether this strategy (ie. launching special cases in a separate stream to execute concurrently) improves your performance significantly will depend on two things:

1. Is the cost of checking actually significant? If the special case is cheap and checked at the top of the kernel, and the kernel is otherwise very expensive, it is probably not worth the complexity.
2. Is API overhead an issue? Launching a kernel is not free, and takes approximately 10us (within an order of magnitude). Your first kernel must take long enough to cover the overhead for the "special" kernel or you may slow down your application.

Other factors to consider include compile time and executable size, both of which will be significantly higher should this pattern be used everywhere in your code.

Comment: Well, if the answer of 1 true, i.e. you have enough data to gain non-negligible benefit from running the full-block version for most of it - then then answer to 2 is probably "not an issue"

Comment: You can have a case where the cost of checking is significant, yet a block takes <10us to complete. In the case where you have only enough blocks total to fill the GPU twice, for example, launch overhead may be a problem.

Comment: How will it be a problem? Assume I have enough blocks to fill the GPU a 100 times. I'm still only making 2 launches. Or maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: If you have enough to fill the GPU 100 times then it probably won't be a problem. That wasn't one of your original assumptions though...

Comment: Well, I did say "the bulk of the data" is the full-block case, but I'll rephrase to hopefully clarify.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Jez in that the kernel launching overhead could be a serious constraint. This is evaluated in a research paper from GaTech:
http://casl.gatech.edu/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/wang_iiswc2014.pdf
The authors here are more concerned about the dynamic parallelism opportunities that exist in GPU codes, and use NVIDIA's [Dynamic Parallelism](http://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/cuda-dynamic-parallelism-api-principles/) mechanism to launch new kernels at runtime.

Follow up work on this research is at (if interested):
http://casl.gatech.edu/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/dtbl_isca42_jin.pdf

Comment: Umm, that article discusses a dynamic parallelism scenario, in which a large number of kernel 'launches' occurs, and that's not what this question is about. Or have I misunderstood you?

Comment: Although the paper is about dynamic parallelism, it brings to light one of the important aspects of modern GPUs i.e. a limit on the number of concurrent kernels that can run (along with the overheads of launching a new kernel). There could be many graphics kernels running on the GPU (e.g. AMD Asynchronous Shaders), with which your compute kernel has to compete for resources . In such a case, one needs to wary of the repercussions of creating new kernels (which somewhat ties to the question you asked).